# Speed up NumPy sums of multiplication of matrices

Tags: python, performance, opencv, numpy, matrix

I'm working with big matrices (numpy arrays) (about `800 x 600`) and I have to make the following operation many times

```
a * (DD ** 2) + 2 * b * DD + c
```

The * sign is the element by element multiplication for matrices.
With cProfile I notice that it takes so much time.
I tried using [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) and it became a little faster but not enough.
Is there a way (algorithmic, mathematical or something else) to make it faster or is this inherently slow?

I'm working using **numpy 1.9**, **python 2.7** with **opencv**.

Comment: And what are all those variables (a, DD, b, c)?

Comment: @marol They are numpy arrays with the same size

Comment: So this is ordinary matrix multiplication? So how b*DD works assuming both has size 800x600, since b's columns amount is not equal to DD's rows amount...

Comment: @marol Sorry I use the wrong term: This is not a matrix multiplacation but a element by element multiplication (like .* multiplication in matlab)

Comment: I mean not to be off-topic since I know what you are asking of. I'm just putting attention to state problem more in details (sizes? what kind of multiplication we have here? normal or product-one?) When comes to optimization, the details are necessary

Comment: @marol you're right, thanks for the improvements to the question

Comment: Try `DD*DD` instead of `DD ** 2`. You should see some improvement.

Comment: Also, try `(a * DD + 2 * b) * DD + c`. This is only 3 ( practically 2)  multiplications. Thsi should definitely be faster.

Comment: @ssm your idea seems to be really good but I can't see any improvment! :( I think it is because numexpr just make that optimization